RTK Query, Api hook , _store_slices_apiScenarioSlice_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.myhookname) is not a function
I am trying to use Redux-Toolkit (RTK) Query and I am getting below error:

(0 ,
store_slices_apiScenarioSlice_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_.useGetScenarioData)
is not a function TypeError: (0 ,
store_slices_apiScenarioSlice_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_.useGetScenarioData)
is not a function
at Scenario (https://localhost:3000/taskpane.js:28598:114)
at renderWithHooks

src/store/slices/apiScenarioSlice.js
import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'
//  import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react' tried already
import { fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3001/api' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getScenarioData: builder.query({
      query: () => '/fetchdata/Scenario',
    }),
  }),
});

// Export hooks for usage in functional components, which are
// auto-generated based on the defined endpoints
export const { useGetScenarioData } = apiSlice;

store.js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import logReducer from './slices/logSlice';
import dialogReducer from './slices/dialogSlice'; // Ensure the import path matches your file structure
import { apiSlice } from './slices/apiScenarioSlice.js'; // tried without .js as well
import { setupListeners } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    log: logReducer,
    dialog: dialogReducer,
    [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
  },
  // Adding the api middleware enables caching, invalidation, polling,
  // and other useful features of `rtk-query`.
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
});
// optional, but required for refetchOnFocus/refetchOnReconnect behaviors
// see `setupListeners` docs - takes an optional callback as the 2nd arg for customization
setupListeners(store.dispatch)

My Provider wrapping app in index.js
  return (
    <OfficeContext.Provider value={officeContext}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <FluentProvider theme={webLightTheme}>
          <HashRouter>
            <App title={title} />
          </HashRouter>
        </FluentProvider>
      </Provider>
    </OfficeContext.Provider>
  );
};

My call of the slice hook in a react function component
import React from "react";
import {
  useGetScenarioData
} from '../store/slices/apiScenarioSlice.js'; // Import RTK Query hook

const Scenario = () => {
  const { data: scenarioData, isLoading, error } = useGetScenarioData(); 
  // Use RTK Query hook thsi line is the one which gives error

    
};

export default Scenario;

I was expecting the hook to work. I tried going though all the items I could find on stackoverflow. I tried changing the file path to .js and use different import libraries with "react" and without "react".

To generate the React hooks import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react' is the correct import, see React Hooks Overview for details.
The issue here is that the API slice generates "use<endpointName>Query" and "use<endpointName>Mutation" named hooks, so if you have query endpoint getScenarioData then the generated hook will be named useGetScenarioDataQuery.
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3001/api' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getScenarioData: builder.query({
      query: () => '/fetchdata/Scenario',
    }),
  }),
});

// Export hooks for usage in functional components, which are
// auto-generated based on the defined endpoints
export const { useGetScenarioDataQuery } = apiSlice;


Did the changes as recommended and it worked like a charm. Dear @Drew Reese many many thanks for your kind suppot.
Got my lesson read your documentation well . Still in documenation it would be nice
"The general format is use(Endpointname)(Query|Mutation) - use is prefixed, the first letter of your endpoint name is capitalized, then Query or Mutation is appended depending on the type." if they would say "Needed format" not general format .

Also just to reinstate for begiiner users like me
import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react' // note import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query' will give error store_slices_apiScenarioSlice_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_.useGetScenarioData) is not a function
